# error which call from main.c to viewcontroller.m as button

Tags: ios6

this is my `main.c`

```
static int l_psd_stop_f(void)
{
    int res;
    int fd_psd_socket;

    if(pthread_mutex_lock(&l_mutex_wrc)) {
        LOG_ERR("Can not lock WRC mutex");
        return -1;
    }
    fd_psd_socket = l_s_wrc.fd_psd;
    l_s_wrc.fd_psd = -1;
    if(pthread_mutex_unlock(&l_mutex_wrc)) {
        LOG_ERR("Can not unlock WRC mutex");
        return -1;}
    res = l_stop_psd_receiver_f(fd_psd_socket);
    fd_psd_socket = -1;
    if(res < 0) {
        LOG_ERR("Can not close PSD socket %d : %s", res, strerror(errno));
        return -1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

i want to call and refer to this codes but it bring me error when i click on the button which run on x-code ipad simulator.

this is on `ViewController.m`

```
- (IBAction)disconnect:(id)sender {

[self l_psd_stop_f];}
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of declaring "`l_psd_stop_f`" in your main.c, put it in your ViewController.m and declare it like this:

```
- (int) l_psd_stop_f
{
    int res;
    int fd_psd_socket;
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
```

And then your "`disconnect`" action will compile and *should* work.

By declaring it as "`static int l_psd_stop_f(void)`" in your main.c, it was a C function that was probably only available to any function calling it from within main.c.  But that function wasn't available to your view controller.

So what I'm having you do is change that C function into an Objective-C method, a member of that ViewController class.

Comment: If it solved your problem you should click the little checkmark icon that appears beneath the vote count for this answer :)

Comment: if like this "static void* l_psd_recv_thread_f(void* p_vp_arg)" how can i change?

Comment: put "`- (int) l_psd_stop_f;`" within your ViewController's .h file, before the "`@end`".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16746828/error-which-call-from-main-c-to-viewcontroller-m-as, can help me ans this question?